# Unable to take off 27” iMac stand

Tags: imac

I got a 2018 27" iMac which I want to mount. I got an Apple VESA toolkit and trying to unlock the hinge to take off the stand but failing.

I watched videos and everyone in the house tried. Isn’t there any Apple video to take the stand off?

Comment: Is this for the iMac Pro or just the plain iMac?

Comment: @Allan iMac Pro 5k

Comment: Thats what I was thinking.  It’s good that you're taking it in...they are needlessly too tight in the tolerances.  The aluminum is soft and you can mess these up without trying.  If the Apple store messes up, its on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a chat with Apple guy who told me the following

> It was decision made by Apple with the release of the 2012 iMac model. The stand can be removed on the 2011 iMac models or earlier.
>
> Yes the VESA mount would work for earlier 27” iMac models. Your model is mountable but would have needed to be purchased with the VESA mount attached to it.

Update: After talking with another Apple support person when buying iMac we can configure it be VESA mount.

Answer (score 1):

No - Apple iMac internals have very delicate connectors and expecially the hinges have tight tolerances, screw torque requirements, strong springs that can get lost if you don’t perform the maintenance properly.

Those training videos are pretty hard to find since most people that pay to become a tech won’t leak them.

You can search on YouTube to learn all the failures when people try to DIY their stand and mounts. Even the vesa mounts are easier than they were in the past, but I would reach out to sales support for help if you’re struggling with it.

It should go easy and if not, you could break things if you force it. Here are techs around the globe - the cost to do a VESA should be very low since it’s quick and easy for someone that’s done a dozen or so.

- https://locate.apple.com

Comment: We did try to be gentle but it’s like the card miss the hatch and I booked with Apple but not before Sunday

Comment: Good - much better to not break things. I remember the first 5 times I worked on these - was on pins and needles until I had successfully done the job. I did have to go in to the complete removal - not the VESA mount that works without opening the Mac. Best of luck @Nofel - sorry it's delayed to visit the tech.

Answer (score 1):

Bypass trying to take off the stand and perhaps use [this device](https://store.officerelief.com/prodcfg/Products/Monitor-Arms/Monitor-Arm-Accessories/IMAD/BMS-VESA-Mount-Adapter-Kit-for-iMac) to use the cable pass-through port on the stand itself as a mounting point without removing the stand. I used one a few years ago and it worked well. The 27" may be a bit too heavy, but you should check with the manufacturer.

Apple also sells [27" iMacs](https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-mac/imac-vesa/27-inch) without a stand, ready for VESA mounting.

Comment: Already spend fortune on VESA mount kit.

Comment: The device was ~$80US.